# Undefined JSON variable in CodeIgniter View

Tags: php, codeigniter

Why am I getting the following errors

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning 
>   Message: Undefined
>   variable: json Filename: views/search_page.php 
>   Line Number: 8
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: Trying to get
>   property of non-object Filename: views/search_page.php Line Number: 8
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: Invalid
>   argument supplied for foreach() Filename: views/search_page.php Line
>   Number: 8

with this code?

**search.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Search extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {

        $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=to%3astackexchange'));

        $this->load->view('search_page', $json);
    }
}

/* End of file search.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/search.php */
```

**search_page.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Twitter Test</title> 
</head>
<body>
<?php foreach ($json->results as $result): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $result->from_user; ?></h2>
<?php endforeach ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: JSON doesn't have variables.

Comment: @Madbreaks: The title is *"Undefined JSON variable in CodeIgniter View"* [JSON](http://json.org) doesn't have variables. But the question seems to be about a PHP variable called `$json`, so perhaps *"Undefined PHP variable `json` ..."*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Pedantic for the sake of being so. The question made it clear what op was asking.

Comment: @Madbreaks: Actually, no. Perhaps consider *not* rushing to judge people you don't know in favor of giving them the benefit of the doubt. Capitalization *matters*, and people see the title in views in which they don't see the question, **and** the question is (actually, *was* -- I've corrected it) tagged `json`, which (upon close reading) is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Valid points. I agree that without the context it would/could be confusing, and `json` was definitely not an appropriate tag.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you are right, its a php variable but the error message referred to it as a json variable (literally speaking)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign the variable you're passing in (`$json`) to a name ("json")

```
$this->load->view('search_page', array('json' => $json));
```

Perhaps a more clear example:

```
$this->load->view('search_page', array('myNeatObject' => $json));

// ...then, in your view, you could

<p>This is the JSON: <?php echo print_r($myNeatObject, true) ?></p>
```

That's how you name a variable for access in a view.